# How can I change the namespace of an attribute in xml with python?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, lxml, xml-namespaces

In my case i have the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as et
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

WSS_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
ACTOR_SCHEMA = "http://xpto"
VERSION_SCHEMA = "2"

NSMAP = {
    'wss': WSS_SCHEMA,
    'S': ACTOR_SCHEMA,
    'at': VERSION_SCHEMA,
}

WSS = ElementMaker(namespace=WSS_SCHEMA, nsmap=NSMAP)

security = WSS.Security()

security.set("{%s}actor" % ACTOR_SCHEMA, ACTOR_SCHEMA)
security.set("{%s}Version" % VERSION_SCHEMA, VERSION_SCHEMA)

print(et.tostring(security, encoding="unicode"))
```

And I am getting this in the output:

> <wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:S="http://xpto" xmlns:at="2" S:actor="http://xpto" at:Version="2"/>

My desired output is this:

> <wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" S:actor="http://xpto" at:Version="2"/>

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can remove these two attributes, or how I can add only the desired attributes with their respective namespaces?

Comment: You need to insert actor and at as regular attributes in Security node, not as namespaces. Removing them from nsmap could be enough.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying, I had already tried that, but when I remove from nsmap still doesn't work either, with your suggestions I got this output:

<wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns0="http://xpto" xmlns:ns1="2" ns0:actor="http://xpto" ns1:Version="2"/>

Comment: If you want namespace qualified attributes you have to define the namespace somewhere in the doc before using them. Something like `xmlns:S="http://xpto" xmlns:at="example.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces must be defined somewhere in the doc before using them.

```
from lxml import etree as et
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

WSS_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
ACTOR_SCHEMA = "http://xpto"
VERSION_SCHEMA = "example.com"

RNSMAP = {
    'S': ACTOR_SCHEMA,
    'at': VERSION_SCHEMA,
}

NSMAP = {
    'wss': WSS_SCHEMA
}


WSS = ElementMaker(namespace=WSS_SCHEMA, nsmap=NSMAP)

security = WSS.Security()

security.set("{%s}actor" % ACTOR_SCHEMA, ACTOR_SCHEMA)
security.set("{%s}Version" % VERSION_SCHEMA, "2")

wrapper = ElementMaker(namespace=ACTOR_SCHEMA, nsmap=RNSMAP)

root = wrapper.Wrapper(security)

print(et.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

Result

```
<S:Wrapper xmlns:S="http://xpto" xmlns:at="example.com">
    <wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" 
        S:actor="http://xpto" at:Version="2"/>
</S:Wrapper>
```

If a single element is required then all namespaces *must* be defined there

```
WSS_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
ACTOR_SCHEMA = "http://xpto"
VERSION_SCHEMA = "example.com"
NSMAP = {
    'wss': WSS_SCHEMA,
    'S': ACTOR_SCHEMA,
    'at': VERSION_SCHEMA,
}
WSS = ElementMaker(namespace=WSS_SCHEMA, nsmap=NSMAP)

security = WSS.Security()

security.set("{%s}actor" % ACTOR_SCHEMA, ACTOR_SCHEMA)
security.set("{%s}Version" % VERSION_SCHEMA, "2")

print(et.tostring(security, encoding="unicode"))
```

Result (manually indented)

```
<wss:Security 
     xmlns:S="http://xpto"
     xmlns:at="example.com" 
     xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
     S:actor="http://xpto"
     at:Version="2"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, but I can't have the Wrapper element, and when I remove it I still have the same problem of not being able to rename the namespaces, is there any to keep the element Security, removing the Wrapper?

Comment: @AndréLeite added the code for a single element. Not exactly what you expected though since namespaces need to be defined there.